# How do I optimize a Macbook Pro to run a particular tab of Chrome?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, google-chrome, memory, performance

My work involves running a specialized Web application. I'm using Google Chrome on a Macbook Air laptop with 8 GB of RAM. With gmail open in one tab and this app open in another Chrome window, my Web app feels sluggish (e.g. the mouse is slow to move on the screen, clicking a link takes seconds to open, etc.). How do I optimize my system to run the Chrome tab that's running this web app? I'm thnking along the lines of:

- Dedicating one CPU core to this Chrome tab.
- Allocating 2GB of physical RAM to this tab.
- I'm willing to buy a new Macbook Pro with 32GB of RAM to improve the performance of this web app.

Comment: A few thoughts - try Edge from M/S, use Mail for the Google Mail rather than the web version, use Safari for the web mail and Chrome for your app.

Comment: I suggest (if possible) trying to run it on Opera instead, since it's similar to Chrome so it'll probably still be able to run the web application, but it's much much faster. Also, your laptop battery will last much longer. I also have a MBA w/ 8 GB of memory, and the battery percentage lasts probably twice as long w/ Opera as Chrome.